# Can you help me identifying an A-4 Skyhawk-like jet?

Tags: aircraft-identification, douglas-a-4-skyhawk

I'm having trouble identifying a jet and am hoping someone can provide some help.  Here is the best picture I've been able to capture.

[image: clearest]

The closest similar jet I've been able to find is the [A-4 Skyhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_A-4_Skyhawk), which shares many of its features, but even in looking through the variants, I can't find an exact match.

The next two pictures aren't as clear, but they show the profile and wing shape, respectively.

[image: profile]
[image: wing shape]

There are three features I've noticed which set it apart from the A-4 variants I've found.

1. Wing shape - It's very curvy, almost Concorde-like.
2. Vertical stabilizer - The forward section of the top of the vertical stabilizer is very sharp, whereas on the A-4's I've seen, this is curved.
3. Antennae - There are *two* antennae; one swept-back antenna directly behind the cockpit and a vertical antenna farther back where the vertical stabilizer begins.

I appreciate any guidance you can provide.  Thank you.

Comment: Later-model A-4s (H+, maybe earlier?) had a squared off tail. Antennae aren't the best way to distinguish aircraft, fwiw, as they can be easily added or removed later in life.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are A-4 Skyhawks all right. They are operated by [Draken International](http://www.drakenintl.com/aircraft-inventory.html) and [provide adversary training](http://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/drakens-a-4k-skyhawks-provide-private-aggressor-duties-1749193650) for USAF (among others); here's a closeup photo of them.

[image: A-4 adversary]

Image from [edwards.af.mil](http://www.edwards.af.mil/shared/media/photodb/photos/2015/08/150821-F-IW159-002.jpg)

Comment: That is indeed it.  Thank you for your thorough answer.

Comment: For completeness, the two depicted appear to be a TA-4(?) and an A-4M: that hump in the back (the one on the right) is a distinctive feature of the A-4M (aka Mongoose IIRC).

Answer (score 11):

Those are Draken International A-4K KAHU Skyhawks, based of of Lakeland regional airport. They have 8 or 9 of them, unfortunately, one was lost last year outside Las Vegas. They are former Royal New Zealand Air Force strike fighters.

These are not your typical A-4 Skyhawk - they are true wolves in sheep's clothing. They have the HOTAS, MFD, radar, and war computers of an F-16 Falcon. Project KAHU was undertaken in late 1980's to early 1990's. All of New Zealand's Skyhawks had their air frames zeroed and then brought into a generation 3+ strike/fighter, almost a 4 a few weapons shy. However with a software upgrade they could have carried the AIM-120 BVR air-to-air missile. But she could carry all the other air to air or mud moving gear of the F-16.

The ones with a hump and tail extension were acquired from another contractor that was bought out by Draken. Those are H models from the IDF.

[image]

A-4K Showing the underside, with some Sidewinder and Maverick missiles.

[image]

All the assembled A-4Ks and TA-4Ks one T-Bird was lost.

[image]

A-4 Skyhawk over Christchurch, NZ

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! This is good info! Please provide sources or citations for the photos.

Comment: Yes, welcome to Aviation.SE!! What does "almost a 4 a few weapons shy" mean? Looks like you were busy typing away and forgot to complete your thought.

Comment: @FreeMan: In context, "3rd generation, almost a 4"  probably refers to [jet fighter generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_fighter_generations)

Comment: a generation 3 fighter is an aircraft like the F-4 Phantom, A-7 Corsair. Aircraft that have air to air and air to ground capabilities with active radar, active ECM and can carry a oat all weapon systems available to NATO or NATO friendly air forces. The A-4 K carried the same version of radar as the F-16.

Answer (score 3):

It's the two-seat training version of the Skyhawk. You can see this in the photo:
there are two pilots seated in tandem.

According to the [A4 Skyhawk Association](http://a4skyhawk.info/content/douglas-4-skyhawk-production-history), there were several two seat models built:

U.S. versions of the two-seat Skyhawk were the TA-4E, quickly changed to TA-4F, the TA-4J, and two special variants, the OA-4M and EA-4F.

Export variations of the two-seater were TA-4G {Australia), TA-4H (Israel), TA-4K (New Zealand), TA-4KU (Kuwait), TA-4PTM (Malaysia), and TA-4S (Singapore).

The ones shown above are probably the US version.

Comment: Any chance you could link a source for this?  It's not that I doubt you, it's just good to cite sources on questions like this.

Comment: Yes of course, added links. I am new here :)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a pair of T-A4K Skyhawks carrying a center-line droptank